# Linking issue after installation of Nvidia Cuda 10.2 + CuDNN 7.5 +OpenCV 4.2.0 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, ubuntu-18.04

I installed NVIDIA drivers, CUDA 10.2, CuDNN 7.5, openCV 4.2.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I tested each installation independently by running some example codes, it works fine.

but when I run  OpenCV+CUDA program like below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include "bits/time.h"

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>

#define TestCUDA true

int main() {
    std::clock_t begin = std::clock();

        try {
            cv::String filename = "/home/raul/Pictures/Screenshot_20170317_105454.png";
            cv::Mat srcHost = cv::imread(filename, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

            for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
                if(TestCUDA) {
                    cv::cuda::GpuMat dst, src;
                    src.upload(srcHost);

                    //cv::cuda::threshold(src,dst,128.0,255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                    cv::cuda::bilateralFilter(src,dst,3,1,1);

                    cv::Mat resultHost;
                    dst.download(resultHost);
                } else {
                    cv::Mat dst;
                    cv::bilateralFilter(srcHost,dst,3,1,1);
                }
            }

            //cv::imshow("Result",resultHost);
            //cv::waitKey();

        } catch(const cv::Exception& ex) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }

    std::clock_t end = std::clock();
    std::cout << double(end-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC  << std::endl;
}
```

i get error as

```
Error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /home/naeem/opencv_contrib-4.2.0/modules/cudaimgproc/src/cuda/bilateral_filter.cu:138: error: (-217:Gpu API call) invalid device function in function 'bilateral_caller'
```

seems like i am stuck..

I compiled using CMAKE and current status of Cuda,CudNN, opencv as below

```
naeem@machine:~/HOME$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
naeem@machine:~/HOME$ nvidia-smi
Mon Apr 20 12:06:13 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    419MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1235      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            28MiB |
|    0      1335      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          47MiB |
|    0      2515      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           171MiB |
|    0      2686      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         116MiB |
|    0      4551      G   /proc/self/exe                                48MiB |
|    0      4552      G   ...-token=57FD8DE5B1D317B30965C435E4973B6F     1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
naeem@machine:~/HOME$ ldconfig -p | grep opencv
    libopencv_xphoto.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.so.4.2
    libopencv_xphoto.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.so
    libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.2
    libopencv_xobjdetect.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.so
    libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.2
    libopencv_ximgproc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so
    libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.2
    libopencv_xfeatures2d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
    libopencv_videostab.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.4.2
    libopencv_videostab.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
    libopencv_videoio.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.2
    libopencv_videoio.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so
    libopencv_video.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.4.2
    libopencv_video.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so
    libopencv_tracking.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_tracking.so.4.2
    libopencv_tracking.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_tracking.so
    libopencv_text.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_text.so.4.2
    libopencv_text.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_text.so
    libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.2
    libopencv_surface_matching.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_surface_matching.so
    libopencv_superres.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.4.2
    libopencv_superres.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so
    libopencv_structured_light.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_structured_light.so.4.2
    libopencv_structured_light.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_structured_light.so
    libopencv_stitching.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.4.2
    libopencv_stitching.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so
    libopencv_stereo.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stereo.so.4.2
    libopencv_stereo.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stereo.so
    libopencv_shape.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.4.2
    libopencv_shape.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so
    libopencv_sfm.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_sfm.so.4.2
    libopencv_sfm.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_sfm.so
    libopencv_saliency.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_saliency.so.4.2
    libopencv_saliency.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_saliency.so
    libopencv_rgbd.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_rgbd.so.4.2
    libopencv_rgbd.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_rgbd.so
    libopencv_reg.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_reg.so.4.2
    libopencv_reg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_reg.so
    libopencv_quality.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_quality.so.4.2
    libopencv_quality.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_quality.so
    libopencv_plot.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_plot.so.4.2
    libopencv_plot.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_plot.so
    libopencv_photo.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.4.2
    libopencv_photo.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
    libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.2
    libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so
    libopencv_optflow.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_optflow.so.4.2
    libopencv_optflow.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_optflow.so
    libopencv_objdetect.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.4.2
    libopencv_objdetect.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so
    libopencv_ml.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.4.2
    libopencv_ml.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so
    libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.2
    libopencv_line_descriptor.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_line_descriptor.so
    libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2
    libopencv_imgproc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.2
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so
    libopencv_img_hash.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_img_hash.so.4.2
    libopencv_img_hash.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_img_hash.so
    libopencv_highgui.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.2
    libopencv_highgui.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
    libopencv_hfs.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hfs.so.4.2
    libopencv_hfs.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hfs.so
    libopencv_hdf.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hdf.so.4.2
    libopencv_hdf.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hdf.so
    libopencv_gapi.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gapi.so.4.2
    libopencv_gapi.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gapi.so
    libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.2
    libopencv_fuzzy.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_fuzzy.so
    libopencv_freetype.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_freetype.so.4.2
    libopencv_freetype.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_freetype.so
    libopencv_flann.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.4.2
    libopencv_flann.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so
    libopencv_features2d.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.2
    libopencv_features2d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so
    libopencv_face.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_face.so.4.2
    libopencv_face.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_face.so
    libopencv_dpm.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dpm.so.4.2
    libopencv_dpm.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dpm.so
    libopencv_dnn_superres.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_superres.so.4.2
    libopencv_dnn_superres.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_superres.so
    libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.2
    libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so
    libopencv_dnn.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.2
    libopencv_dnn.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so
    libopencv_datasets.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_datasets.so.4.2
    libopencv_datasets.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_datasets.so
    libopencv_cudev.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudev.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudev.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudev.so
    libopencv_cudawarping.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudawarping.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so
    libopencv_cudastereo.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudastereo.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so
    libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudaoptflow.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so
    libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so
    libopencv_cudalegacy.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudalegacy.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so
    libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudaimgproc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so
    libopencv_cudafilters.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudafilters.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so
    libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so
    libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudabgsegm.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so
    libopencv_cudaarithm.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.4.2
    libopencv_cudaarithm.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so
    libopencv_core.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.2
    libopencv_core.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
    libopencv_ccalib.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ccalib.so.4.2
    libopencv_ccalib.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ccalib.so
    libopencv_calib3d.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.2
    libopencv_calib3d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
    libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.2
    libopencv_bioinspired.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bioinspired.so
    libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.2
    libopencv_bgsegm.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bgsegm.so
    libopencv_aruco.so.4.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.4.2
    libopencv_aruco.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so
```

Comment: The OpenCV version you have installed has not been built with support for your GPU. This is not a linking problem

Comment: How do we get the correct version with respect to the gpu??

Comment: Either build it yourself from source or go and find a pre-built version with compute 6.1 support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks talnomies. Its was build using wrong architecture. When i matched cc6.1 it works fine

cmake:

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-6 -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-4.2.0/modules -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_CUDNN=ON -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=6.1 -D CUDA_GENERATION=Pascal \  ..
```